# Hide a custom UITableViewCell from another UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two cells, let's say cell A and cell B in my app. Both of them have their own class, `class CellA : UITableViewCell` and `class CellB : UITableViewCell`.

I wish to hide cell B when user tap on a button in cell A.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: are there only 2 cells in the tableview?

Comment: @SahebRoy No there are some other cells

Comment: then what cells are you trying to hide? press button on any class A cells and hide all Class B cells?

Comment: @SahebRoy I've edited the question. Hope it's clear enough

Comment: Still not clear, there are 6 cells 3 of each classes, now if you press Any class A cells button will all the 3 cells of class B hide?

Comment: Other cells have their own classes. There is one and only one cell for each class.

Comment: I have added an answer i hope it solves your problem

Comment: While tap on the button you can get button Event then, hide the cell.

Comment: @VineeshTP but how can I access `CellB : UITableViewCell` inside `CellA : UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: both cells are  display in same TableView right ? then u can add the button action like  [CellB.button addTarget..... ], then reduce the cell index and reload the tableView.

Comment: @VineeshTP Oh I didn't know I could add target in table view controller. I will try it out, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to hide cell B when tapping on a button in cell A (not the cell A itself), I think the good way is just to post a notification when clicking the button, let the UIViewController know it,then remove the datasouce of cellB and reloadData.

Comment: could you explain more on posting notification between classes? I know how to push local notification, but not notification between classes.

Comment: nvm, I already found some tutorials on  `NSNotificationCenter`. Thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/Glow-Inc/GLPubSub   You can also use this which is a capsulation of NSNotificationCenter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Static tableview content, just create two outlet of cell, lets say Cell1 and Cell2 with respective class of A and B with action methods `actn_methodCell1` and `actn_methodCell2`

```
-(void)actn_methodCell1{ //action method for button in cell1
Cell2.hidden = YES;
[self.tableview reloadData];
}
 -(void)actn_methodCell2{ //action method for button in cell2
Cell1.hidden = YES;
[self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

OR If you are using prototype tableview then, code this in `didSelectCell`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
if([cell isKindOfClass:[A class]]){
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableview) {
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[B class]]){
        cell.hidden = YES;
    }
}
}
else if ([cell isKindOfClass:[B class]]){  
for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableview) {
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[A class]]){
        cell.hidden = YES;
    }
}
}
[self.tableview reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: I am using prototype tableview, but the problem is I want to hide cell B when I tap the button in cell A, not cell A itself.

Comment: yes this code that does only., just did a typo there check the EDIT